# Is it legal to copy large amount of data peer to peer in Canada

Tags: copyright, internet, canada

Is it legal to transfer large amounts of encrypted data peer to peer in Canada?

1. I transfer data from my friend PC in another country.
2. The **data is encrypted**, so nobody can ever know which data it is.

An article from 2006 states the following:

> In Canada, the Copyright Act protects all works and prohibits the confection of copies or the communication to the public without authorization. *Thus, as a general rule, Internet file-sharing is illegal.*

Is it true? Is it about any file-sharing or only for copyrighted works? Does it mean that file-transfer is also illegal because I don't share I copy onto my PC.

Comment: The operative part of your quote is “without authorisation”.  If you have authorisation from the copyright holder to distribute to another party, you are fine.  If you are distributing to yourself, even by uploading to another service (think AWS or Azure) then you are also fine.

Comment: @Moo the very important piece here is that data is encrypted, so nobody able to tell what is it. Maybe this is my friend's wedding video.

Comment: Doesnt matter - most internet traffic is encrypted these days.  If encryption was “bad” then no one could use https, banking sites or VPNs.

Comment: @Moo no this matters. Torrents aren't encrypted in some sense. A copyright holder can start seeding and then send infringement notice to everybody who received his content. And he knows exactly which content. But I accept content only from a trusted source and nobody can see what is inside.

Comment: Yeah, i think you are thinking about this too much - copyright infringement is copyright infringement, regardless of the means of transport and whether you get caught or not. And the flip side is also true - if you have permission from the copyright holder then you can transfer files any way you like.

Comment: @Moo thanks that was the question. They would need to prove that content is copyrighted to sue me. But will not be able to do it because it was encrypted.

Comment: Be wary if that is your approach - many people have relied on being untraceable due to encryption and have found that the implementation was leaky.  See the issues around Tor traffic being traced for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption of data is relevant only if your permission from the copyright holder is contingent on the data being encrypted. First, if you did not create the content and it is protected by copyright (generally it is), you have to have permission to copy it. If the rights-holder says "you may copy it or transfer it to X, but only if you use a (particular) secure file transfer protocol", then you can't copy / transfer it unencrypted. But if you hold the copyright, then you can do whatever you want with the content.

Comment: So, there is no restriction to transfer peer-to-peer my own content? If you could provide a reference to read more about it that would be wonderful.

Comment: "The reading" is fairly long and opaque: https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-42/FullText.html. The core is that the creator has "the sole right to produce or reproduce the work", and that covers all means of reproduction – there isn't a specific law about peer-to-peer "sharing" rights.